# Why can't I jump backforward when pressing Shift+Tab key in Ultisnips?

Tags: plugin-ultisnips, snippets

I have added the line in `.vimrc`:

```
let g:UltiSnipsJumpBackwardTrigger="<s-tab>"
```

Edit a `test.py`, type `ifee` and <kbd>Tab</kbd> to expand it; upon pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd>, the cursor jumps into next region. Why can't I jump back when pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> key?

Please watch the screenshot:

[JumpBackward failed](https://asciinema.org/a/bnmnTTOt7mouxB6GdEdOsnkV5)

It work for me.

```
let g:UltiSnipsJumpBackwardTrigger="<c-b>"
```

But i don't know why it can't do.

```
let g:UltiSnipsJumpBackwardTrigger="<s-tab>"
```

Comment: Strange, it works for me. Try restarting vim?

Comment: Does it work if you use another key mapping to jump backwards, say `<C-b>`? I am guessing that this issue is linked to terminal escape sequences, though I'm not an expert at that.. perhaps someone else could chime in...